# how to show only timestamp, rssi and mac-address of beacon

Tags: android, timestamp

```
private final ThreadLocal<ScanCallback> mScanCallback = new ThreadLocal<ScanCallback>() {

    @Override
    protected ScanCallback initialValue() {
        return new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                ScanRecord btScanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
                //Log.i(TAG,"new johoksdfjkhdfsj");//Not Called
                if (btScanRecord != null) {
                }
                Connect();
                //Log.i(TAG,"new johoksdfjkhdfsj");//Not Called
            }

            @Override
            public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                    Log.i("ScanResult-Results", sr.toString());
                    //Log.i(TAG, sr.toString());//not called
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

I want only rssi, timestamp and mac-address but i think this code gives me some other string also like manufacturer details ,advertise flags etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this BLE Scan listener:

```
 public BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
                new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // also get address using
                          // device.getAddress();
                           addDevice(device,rssi);  

                          String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                         Log.e("In h:m:s"," "+currentDateTimeString);

                        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                        String ts = tsLong.toString();
                        Log.e("In miliseconds"," "+ts);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

I hope this work.

Comment: I added but some errors are showing can you please tell me how to remove this error bcoz iam new in android so i dont know. Thanks in advance. BluetoothAdapter is not public in this package, cannot be accessed from outside package. This is the error

Comment: Thanks a lot but it gives rssi and mac-add but didn't give the timestamp so  can you give any idea

Comment: change private to public. .i.e. private BluetoothAdapter. To public BluetoothAdapter.

Comment: check edited answer. Let me know if this is correct.